# Is "Signifying nothing" an example of litotes?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, poetry, figures-of-speech, shakespeare

In Macbeth's *Tomorrow* speech

> To-morrow, and to-morrow, and to-morrow,
> Creeps in this petty pace from day to day,
> To the last syllable of recorded time;
> And all our yesterdays have lighted fools
> The way to dusty death.
> Out, out, brief candle!
> Life's but a walking shadow, a poor player
> That struts and frets his hour upon the stage
> And then is heard no more.
> It is a tale
> Told by an idiot, full of sound and fury
> Signifying nothing."
> — Macbeth (Act 5, Scene 5, lines 17-28)

is the last line *Signifying nothing* litotes?

I have to analyze this segment for school, and I'm a little unclear of what litotes is in practice.

Comment: BTW, *litote* isn't a word - you should say "Is the last line an example of litotes?"

Comment: I think there is usually an *s* at the end of *litotes*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a figure of speech *litotes* means understatement for ironic emphasis, often by denying the opposite.

Examples form Shakespeare include "not without cause" [Julius Caesar] or "we have seen better days" [As You Like It].  I would not say "signifying nothing" was an example, as Macbeth means precisely what he says about the futility of human existence.

Comment: But so does 'not without cause'. As 'signify' [here] means 'having an [important] meaning, which is ...', ie 'significant ...', attesting the opposite is correspondingly litotes (denying any significance).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "not without cause" is understatement, and that is the key to litotes: Antony could have said "You loved Caesar because he was Rome's greatest leader" but did not because of the nature of his oration.  By contrast, Macbeth's analysis that life signifies nothing is not an understated version of saying life is meaningless.

Comment: Nordquist includes "The grave's a fine a private place,
But none, I think, do there embrace." (Andrew Marvell, "To His Coy Mistress") as an example of litotes. The use of a negative [and this includes zero]  _tone, situation obtaining_ where a positive might well be expected. It depends on precising definitions.

Answer (score 8):

No.  *[Litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes)* is "a form of understatement, always deliberate and with the intention of emphasis."  An example of litotes could be "not bad" (which means "good"), or "you are not wrong" (meaning "you are right").  It is principally defined by a double negative.

*Signifying nothing* does not include a denial of the opposite, and neither is it an understatement.  It is therefore not an example of litotes.